# ERROR - JmsStore Store with WSO2 EI 1.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

ERROR - JmsStore Store [PaymentRequestJMSMessageSre]. Could not create a new connection to the broker. Initial Context Factory:rg.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory]; Provider URL:[conf/jn.properties]; Connection Factory:[null].

Comment: Can you add your config? Just the error message is not enough to be able to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Looks like you're using WSO2 MB as the JMS broker. Did you copy the required client libraries from the MB to ESB?